# How to create a pattern that does overlap the boundary

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, illustrator-scripting

Working with the latest version of Adobe Illustrator I need to create a pattern that fills within the boundary of a polygon but doesn't clip the individual objects that make up that pattern. My existing attempts result in fig.1 but I'm trying to achieve fig.2

[image: Pattern overlapping boundary]

Answer (score 1):

With a Pattern Swatch, as defined in Illustrator, it is **not possible** to accomplish this.

Pattern swatches in Illustrator **always** clip to the tile bounds. There's no feature or mechanism to define objects within a pattern that ignore any tile clipping. In fact, the entire point of a pattern is to repeat to the clipping.

That being posted, you *may* be able to apply a pattern swatch then *expand* the object's appearance and then remove the resulting clipping path. This will show whole objects within the pattern. You would then need to *manually* remove anything which maybe superfluous. There are generally *a lot* of superfluous objects when doing this. I'm uncertain if it would be easier to merely create the circles you want *without* a pattern, or to delete the extra objects after expanding a pattern. Somewhat depends upon the artwork.

---

For something such as your sample image.... You *may* find that merely using **dashed strokes** on a series of *paths* is easier. Combined with a few manually placed circles when you need a single circle.

[image]

You *do* have to watch path lengths with this method. Despite what one would think, the dashes *will* adjust if a path is slightly too short/long for full dashes. As you can see in the image above, none of the dashes line up between paths. Each path needs to be a length that is *evenly divisible* by the stroke weight + the gap distance (36pts in the image above) in order for the dashes to all line up.

---

Perhaps the best (easiest) method, given the sample image, may be to use a **Pattern Brush** applied to paths. This would help ensure the dots line up between paths without the necessity of measuring path lengths....

[image]