# How do I (re)create something similar to these? What's the process to align all those circles to create shape without manual work?

Tags: vector, grids, graph

I'm working on a project where something similar to this (maybe even animated) would fit perfectly, but I don't know how to create something similar (I want to create mountain shapes or buildings that may resemble a chart or levels)

Here are the designs I'm asking about: https://www.behance.net/gallery/29501907/Colorpongcom-Dataism-vector-bundle

Picture example too: [image]

Thank you!

Comment: In essence your asking how a doubly nested for loop works. This isn't really a graphics design question, but i have covered this [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80938/how-to-create-a-line-graph-around-a-circle/80958#80958) so the only thing is you replace lines with dots and there are more than one and its in cartesian coordinates not circular ones.

Comment: I see! Well, I have to research more into that, thank you for the starting point! I don't really understand what's going on there for now, but I will try to figure it out! Thank you again, amazing resource!

Comment: Ok, one question: How do I figure out what data I should dump there to achieve a similar design?

Comment: There's actually a lot of ways to create these sorts of things. And the Behance link you share has a lot of different visualizations, each not created in the exact same way most likely. If you have a more specific question, we may be able to help. As is, we probably can't be that useful

Comment: @ZachSaucier I want to do something like in the image I shared, but instead of the chart to recreate mountains.

Comment: This Matterhorn photo https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Matterhorn_as_seen_from_Zermatt%2C_Wallis%2C_Switzerland%2C_2012_August.jpg/800px-Matterhorn_as_seen_from_Zermatt%2C_Wallis%2C_Switzerland%2C_2012_August.jpg is converted in GIMP to this dithered one bit image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxto2.jpg The job is a low effort one.

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't** need actual data visualization and merely want to mimic the overall concept...

Art Brushes in **Illustrator** could be used...

[image]

... single path with an Art Brush applied, then effects used to rotate, duplicate, and distort the path.

---

The Art Brush consist of merely a slightly larger circle, then a dashed stroke to appear as dots..

[image] [image]

If you're unfamiliar with how to create a dashed stroke to appear as dots... examine the **Stroke Panel** in the image above - Stroke weight determines diameter of dot, rounded caps makes then rounded, 0 dash makes circles, and the gap is the space between dots.

When creating the Art Brush, set the **Brush Scale Options** to `Stretch Between Guides` and make certain that larger circle is *not* within the guides.

[image]

---

Then it's merely a matter of drawing...

Circular forms are fairly easy with transform effects....

[image]

But there are many, many other possibilities...

[image]

[image]
<sup>(Open in new window to see larger and you'll see it's all dots.)</sup>

.. and, of course, one can duplicate forms as well as manually draw paths with the Art Brush applied to them.

Ot adjust the `Scale` of the Art Brush for more variation...

[image]

Comment: Could you share the art brush you used, please?

Comment: @Edouard It's simply a (larger) circle and dashed line. There's nothing more to it. If you don't know how to create the dashed line which appears like "dots" see here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/145034/how-to-create-a-pattern-that-does-overlap-the-boundary/145037#145037 - Set the Art Brush to "stretch Between Guides" and adjust the guides so they do *not* encompass that larger circle.